# Can not consume Kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I have set up a Kafka broker with 1 partition and 1 replication factor.
I am able to produce messages ,but i can not consume them .I am not getting any error it just looks like waiting for something.
I am trying to consume them with the command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-kafka-topic --from-beginning
```

**Kafka config**

```
broker.id=1
listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka_1-logs
```

**Zookeeper log** (last messages)

```
[2019-11-04 22:49:28,859] INFO Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56069 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2019-11-04 22:49:28,860] INFO Client attempting to establish new session
at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56069 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-11-04 22:49:28,990] INFO Established session 0x1000baf48760002 with
negotiated timeout 6000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56069 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-11-04 22:49:29,246] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000baf48760002 type:multi cxid:0xc5 zxid:0x25e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

**Producer**

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-kafka-topic
>hello
>howdy
>121
>
```

**P.S** I am following this [guide](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/11/22/how-to-install-and-run-kafka/)

**Update**
I am creating the topic upfront.If i do not do that and i try to publish a message i get an error message with `LEADER UNAVAILABLE`

I have checked the logs and there's nothing in the server log from the moment i try to consume the message.The terminal in the meantime waits indefinitely.

**Controller.log**

```
> [2019-11-05 23:30:01,118] DEBUG [Controller id=1] Topics not in
> preferred replica for broker 0 Map()
> (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2019-11-05 23:30:01,118] TRACE
> [Controller id=1] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.0
> (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Have you tried the official quick start guide at http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart?

Comment: Also try to terminate the producer process.

Comment: It does not throw any error it just waits.

Comment: what's the Kafka log. Does it show that the consumer joined a consumer group to read from the topic? From the producer log it seems that you created the topic upfront right? (it's because I don't see the transient error of LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE when the auto topic creation is enabled but the broker has to create it when the first message comes from the producer). Anyway I would try the official quickstart even because there is no need to change the Kafka configuration for having a one broker cluster up and running. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart

Comment: can you check replication factor on the `__consumer_offsets` topic?

Comment: @mazaneicha How can i do that ? Also i have run the official quickstart as you mentioned  and still the consumer just waits indefinitely .

Comment: Check `offsets.topic.replication.factor` in server.properties?

Comment: I have made it work using a cmd terminal .It worked out of the box. All these problems encountered were somehow linked to using `git for windows` terminal.